# Email form on SharePoint with Anonymous Access?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, infopath, forms-authentication

I've used the standard javascript that makes a POST to this api:
/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail

However, I noticed that this is only functional for authenticated users. We want to create an emailed form on a page and use this method of sending the form. What alternative would enable to the server to do the API post?

This is an on-premise Sharepoint 2013 server.

Comment: What about using a workflow to send the email?

Comment: how would that be done? can that be done purely using SharePoint Designer? We don't have central admin privileges btw.

Comment: If the users fill a form, then this form is saved in a list, right? Then the workflow for this list can send an email (because you can give high privilege to a workflow: there are plenty documentation about it).

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 platform workflow can send email to external users.

You can create a 2010 designer workflow or trigger the 2010 workflow via 2013 workflow. [Details](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8tsrU0Za1R4J:https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rajbugga/2013/10/15/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-send-emails-to-external-email-addresses-sharepoint-2013-workflows/%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sg) for your reference.